# Images of SharePoint site is not visible after migration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

We did migration of sharepoint 2007 site to different server to SharePoint 2010.
After migration site is functioning normally but not showing images on the pages, instead of image cross sign is appearing on the page.
Can someone please help.
I have copied images of old server to new server in 14 hive Templates\Images folder.
I have checked properties of image, there Type,Size,Modified,Created these attributes value is "Not Available"

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Url of the image your site pointing and check if its present on your site.

Comment: yes did that,images exisit at that location but still not getting rendered on the page.

Comment: Please type that URL on your browser and check it is opening properly.

Comment: tried this,image is not getting rendered.Below error occured.
Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server.
What needs to do then..Image exists at path.

Comment: You can try the image with some different extension.

Comment: you means to say different image or same image with different extension. can you plz tell me in detail.

Comment: Save same image with different extension and check. Can you provide me the URL which you are using.

Comment: here it is - 
"ht tp://yrmse1/_layouts/images/tvplus.gif"

Comment: Whats is the physical path of your image?

Comment: physical path is => C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

Comment: try with png file extension.

Comment: I saved typlus img as png and tried opening using url still there is same error